# Why am I getting a 'Subquery returned more than 1 value' error on SQL Server when there is no subquery?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm getting the following error when trying to run a very simple query on a SQL Server database from a PHP script...

> SQLSTATE[21000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when
>   the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used
>   as an expression. (SQL: select * from [NAVItems] where [Brand] =
>   DELINTE)

As you can see, there is no subquery. I'm just trying to pull a list of product records of a specific brand. The strange thing is, it only happens with this one brand, DELINTE. For example...

```
select * from [NAVItems] where [Brand] = 'FALKEN';
```

...works fine.

Also, the query works for DELINTE if I change the selection to specific fields instead of *. For example...

```
select [Style] from [NAVItems] where [Brand] = 'DELINTE';
```

...also works fine.

But...

```
select * from [NAVItems] where [Brand] = 'DELINTE';
```

...keeps throwing the above error.

I'm so confused. Any idea why it might be doing this? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I found the problem. Yes there was a subquery in the view, and there were some duplicate records in a related table, causing the error. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Is this query being executed as a sub-query for a larger query not mentioned in the question?  I don't understand why you would get that error if it wasn't...

Comment: Where you are running this query? Can you put the full code?

Comment: Is NAVItems perhaps a view?

Comment: I notice the actual error message reproduced above does *not* put the literal DELINTE in quotes. Was the error encountered with the constant value unquoted, perchance?

Comment: In this particular case I'm using Laravel's query builder. So as a test I'm simply running the following code...

    $products = DB::connection('nav')->table('NAVItems')->select('*')->where('Brand', '=', 'DELINTE')->get();
        dd($products);

Comment: @SeanLange - I believe it is a view, yes. Why do you ask?

Comment: Can you script the view and show it here?

Comment: @Jordy, The view could contain subsqueries even when the query using the view does not have a subquery.

Comment: Yeah I would be willing to bet the view has a subquery that was not built correctly.